# Format date in validation message with Laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, formatdatetime

In my database i have date field in format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. What I want is, that this date is always bigger then this moment, when adding new item in database. I check this with laravel's validator:

`Validator::make->($request->all(), [
     'date'=>'date|after:'.date(Y-m-d H:i:s)
]);`

The problem is, that my page is in different languages, and each language has different date formats. Sometimes I want default format, sometimes i want `d.m.Y H:i:s`, and so on..
I made translations for different languages in `resources/lang` directory. For validation, I translated existing `validation.php` file, but the problem is, I don't know how to format date, if that is even possible with this approach. For now, my date is always in default format, the one I compare my input with. My `validation.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php

return [
   'after' => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.'
];
```

My question now is, how to format `:date` attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried already:

```
'after' => 'The :attribute must be date after'.date(format, strtotime(':date'))
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it solves your problem, but I tested this:

```
$dateFormat = 'j.n.Y';
$this->validate($request, [
  'date' => 'date_format:'.$dateFormat.'|after:' . now()->format($dateFormat)
]);
```

and it seems to work.
Changing the `$dateFormat`, it displays errors correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The dates will be always passed into the PHP strtotime function.

To make date always bigger than this moment you can simply use the term **now**.
Laravel make it pretty simple as below.

```
Validator::make->($request->all(), [
 'date'=>'date|after:now'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not actually what i am looking for. My validation works correctly, the problem I am having is with formatting date in validation message. Even if I use your approach, and put now in attributes and translate it, validation message still returns :date as now.

Comment: I would be satisfied if "now" would be translated, but I still prefer acutal date.